# How can you split a multi-valued attribute in an xml file using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

So, I have an xml data that is quite chaotic and needed to parse it so that I can insert it to a database.

Here is an example of the XML :

```
<GenericItem html='ID: AAA1&lt;br/&gt;Age: 12&lt;br/&gt;Name: Baryk &lt;'>
   Employee:
</GenericItem>
```

How can I split the value of the html tag so that I can get the name, age, and ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

You just need to do some string manipulation/cleaning to get the data you want. I just printed it, you can save it in a variable if you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = "<GenericItem html='ID: AAA1&lt;br/&gt;Age: 12&lt;br/&gt;Name: Baryk &lt;'>Employee:</GenericItem>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for each in soup.find("genericitem").get("html").split("<br/>"):
    print(each.split(":")[1].replace("<", "").strip())
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this one works! It is simple and nice :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, what if it is in a file with multiple GenericItem tag. How can I split the tag value until end of file ?

Comment: You have to use `find_all` on that tag and it will return list of tag so you have to iterate over that

Comment: you can use find_all which will return the list and then loop over it as @BhavyaParikh suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken your data as `html`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""<GenericItem html='ID: AAA1&lt;br/&gt;Age: 12&lt;br/&gt;Name: Baryk &lt;'>
   Employee:
</GenericItem>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
```

I have find `genericitem` tag and split according to `<br/>` and inside loop spliting usign `:` to take value as key-value pair adding to `data_dict`

```
dict_data={}
tag=soup.find("genericitem")['html'].split("<br/>")
for data in tag:
    info=data.split(":")
    value=info[0]
    data=info[1].strip()
    dict_data[value]=data
```

Output:

```
{'ID': 'AAA1', 'Age': '12', 'Name': 'Baryk <'}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help , this one also works ! I will use it for another project of mine. You made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

You can parse and re-parse with BeautifulSoup and 'lxml'

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

to_parse = '''<GenericItem html='ID: AAA1&lt;br/&gt;Age: 12&lt;br/&gt;Name: Baryk &lt;'>
   Employee:
</GenericItem>'''

soup = bs(to_parse, 'lxml')
print([i.split(': ')[-1] for i in bs(soup.select_one('genericitem')['html'], 'lxml').select_one('p').stripped_strings])
```